# Counting number of keys that have specific values in a range

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, dictionary, scipy

I have the following problem. I have a dictionary with coordinates as keys and values that lay between 0 and something like 0.0026. Now I want to count the number of keys that have values between 0.0013 and 0.0026 for example. How can I do that?

For example:

```
dict1 ={(0,1,2):"0.0026",(0,4,2):"0.0011",(0,5,2):"0.0018"}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply use a `sum` with a conditional generator expression:

```
>>> sum(1 for val in dict1.values() if 0.0013 < float(val) < 0.0026)
1
```

If you want to use "normal" `for`-loops you could also use:

```
sum_ = 0
for val in dict1.values():
    if 0.0013 < float(val) < 0.0026:
        sum_ += 1
```

Depending on your understanding of "between" you need to change the `<` to `<=`.